# Как с приемлемой надежностью протестировать программный код, реализующий генетический алгоритм?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, консоль, генетический-алгоритм

Имеется приложение, разработанное индивидуально только мной, реализующее генетический алгоритм. Результат работы получается случайным в силу самого алгоритма. Можно проверить только, что он не исказил исходные данные. Приложение компонует упаковку (набор коробок, помещаемых в ящик) и результат компоновки можно увидеть в CAD-системе SolidWorks. Приложение реализовано в виде консольной программы C++, содержащей несколько классов с методами и структур. Визуализация компоновки в SolidWorks реализована с помощью другого приложения, которое не нуждается в тестировании. Разработка велась в Visual Studio 2022.

Существует ли какая-нибудь общая методология для тестирования такого рода приложений, доступная для непрофессионала в области программирования? Может есть конкретный пакет для Visual Studio, реализующий функциональность тестирования. Хотелось бы убедиться с приемлемым уровнем надежности, что алгоритм работает безошибочно. Насколько приемлем уровень - сказать сложно. Мне достаточно для ответа узнать только инструмент/фреймворк/метод, подходящий для этой задачи.

Answer (score 3):

По идее, у вас типичный "черный ящик". На входе аргументы, на выходе компоновки.

Как его протестировать? Как и всякий другой черный ящик - подавайте на вход значения и проверяйте что результаты соответствуют ожиданиям. Какие у вас ожидания и что такое "приемлемая надежность" - это придется формализовать только вам ...

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! Попробую пояснить, что меня сподвигло написать этот вопрос. Меня смущает, то, что в основе алгоритма лежит определенная логика. Я уже столкнулся с тем, что несколько опечаток искажают логику работы. Но отслеживать корректность вычислений на каждом этапе, например, с помощью инструментов отладки, достаточно трудоемко, и не факт, что инструменты отадки быстро помогут отследить все пути выполнения кода. Вот с этим я и хотел бы как-то бороться. А эффективность и приемлемость алгоритма отслеживать по визуальной оценке компоновки и целевой функции.

Comment: *"в основе алгоритма лежит определенная логика"* - в основе любого алгоритма лежит определенная логика ..

Comment: *"отслеживать корректность вычислений на каждом этапе .. достаточно трудоемко"* - сложные задачи требуют сложных "строительных лесов"

Comment: *"эффективность и приемлемость алгоритма отслеживать по визуальной оценке компоновки и целевой функции"* - визуальная оценка "на глаз" - это плохо. Лучше все же формализовать. Если есть целевая функция - отлично. Просто может быть вы не совсем то в итоге меряете, что нужно?

Comment: Я меряю плотность упаковки по целевой функции. Чтобы пустоты много не было. А визуально сравниваю ее с ручной компоновкой: удобно ли будет фиксировать коробки стрейч-пленкой на поддоне или придется делать какие-то дополнительные действия для фиксации. Пока не проработал до конца этот вопрос.

Comment: Вы верно догадываетесь, что одна из проблем генетических алгоритмов как раз в том, чтобы правильно сформулировать целевую функцию. Иначе получится, то, что называется GIGO - garbage in - garbage out.